# Bootstrap DROPDOWN "Justified button groups" not working with Jquery 3.1, but work with 2.1?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, versioning

I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong. If I call jQuery 2.1 it works, 3.1 it doesn't. I'm talking specifically about the dropdown functionality within the topnav. The topnav displays fine. Expanding the dropdown doesn't work.

The console just says bootstrap needs jquery 1.9 or higher.

```
 <div class="container">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Single Use</span>
    </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-wide">
    <li><a href="#" class='requestTypeButton'>Something</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class='requestTypeButton'>Something 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <a class="btn btn-primary requestTypeButton" href="#" role="button">Something 3</a>
</div>
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <a class="btn btn-primary requestTypeButton" href="#" role="button">Something 4</a>
</div>
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <a class="btn btn-primary requestTypeButton" href="#" role="button">Something 5</a>
</div>
```

Comment: could you add more information, pictures or similar of both desired behaviour, and the opposite? It's hard to understand specifically what you mean by "not working". Is it not expanding to show the options? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: I thought by saying the dropdown functionality doesn't work it would imply that it's not expanding. I'll add that to my question up top.

Comment: It was the most likely option, but you'd be surprised how many non-intuitive "not working" there are on this site :). Did you check the console? any error messages? Can you see any differences in the inspector?

Comment: It says I need jQuery 1.9 or higher. I can't imagine jquery 3+ would break the functionality?

Comment: I'm not the biggest expert here, but I'll give it a shot. First of all, there is a close tag for a span in there, 4th line. But no start tag for it.

Comment: And which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- not working -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- working -->

Comment: Tried to play around with it, but I can't seem to setup a similar workspace here. But I'll give you a +1 for making a good question!

Comment: Thanks for trying! And finding that span tag!

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap introduced support for JQuery 3 in Bootstrap version 3.3.7.

See the changelog here:
http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2016/07/25/bootstrap-3-3-7-released/